# Best way to deal with a db table that will have lots of rows

Tags: database, sqlite

Preface that I am really new to building dbs.

I am parsing data I retrieve and storing some information in a db.  The data is a group of files ( > 10k files) in which I parse some ids and quantities out of.  Then I store said information in tthe db.  Sum up all the counts for each ID then store in the db for the total counts.  Rinse and repeat for each day.

The structure I have defined at the moment is this:

```
Table itemsPerDay {
   itemId integer
   dateAddedId integer
   count integer 
}

Table datesPulled {
    id integer [primary key]
    datePulled timestamp
}

Ref: datesPulled.id > itemsPerDay.dateAddedId
```

My concern is this:  There are going to be 20k plus ids that are written, each day, meaning that 20k rows in the table per day.  This seems to me it can explode very quickly.

Is there a better way of laying it out so it won't kill performance say a month in the future?

Going to be using sqlite and C#.

Comment: 20k rows per day is 7.3m rows in a year. with just a few integers and datestamps plus metadata and other overhead, probably still under 200mb - You can do that on your mobile phone.